# Kubernetes - kube-system pods in master node keep restarting after worker node joins

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, flannel, weave

I have followed this [tutorial](https://blog.kublr.com/how-to-install-a-single-master-kubernetes-k8s-cluster-34ec16efefff) and this [tutorial](https://blog.alexellis.io/kubernetes-in-10-minutes/) and [this one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) but am facing the same issue for last 3 days.

I am able to set up the master node correctly with the following steps:

```
kubeadm init

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

export kubever=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d ‘\’)
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$kubever"
```

and everything seems fine in

```
kubectl get all --namespace=kube-system
```

then,

on the worker node:

```
kubeadm join --token 864655.fdf6d0b389867b79 192.168.100.17:6443 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:a2d840808b17b53b9612e6271ccde489f13dbede7d354f97188d0faa9e210af2
```

The output seems fine and is as below:

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
  [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
[preflight] Starting the kubelet service
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "192.168.100.17:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://192.168.100.17:6443"
[discovery] Requesting info from "https://192.168.100.17:6443" again to validate TLS against the pinned public key
[discovery] Cluster info signature and contents are valid and TLS certificate validates against pinned roots, will use API Server "192.168.100.17:6443"
[discovery] Successfully established connection with API Server "192.168.100.17:6443"

This node has joined the cluster:
* Certificate signing request was sent to master and a response
  was received.
* The Kubelet was informed of the new secure connection details.

Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the master to see this node join the cluster.
```

*BUT* as soon as I run this command, all hell breaks loose. The

```
kubectl get all --namespace=kube-system
```

starts showing that all pods are kind of restarting all the time. the status keeps changing between Pending and Running, and at time some of the pods will even disappear and may have ContainerCreating status etc.

```
NAME                                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
po/etcd-ubuntu                      0/1       Pending   0          0s
po/kube-controller-manager-ubuntu   0/1       Pending   0          0s
po/kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-cmcfk         3/3       Running   0          13m
po/kube-proxy-2chb6                 1/1       Running   0          13m
po/kube-scheduler-ubuntu            0/1       Pending   0          0s
po/weave-net-ptdxr                  2/2       Running   0          11m
```

I have also tried the second tutorial, with flannel, and get the exact same issue.

*My Set Up*

I created two new VMs with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 17.10 on VMware with 2 processor/2core 6 GB of ram and 50 GB hard disk each. My physical machine is a i7-6700k with 32gb of ram.
I installed kubeadm, kubelet and docker on both of them and then followed the steps as mentioned above.

I have also tried switching between NAT and Bridge on VMware and nothing changed.

The initial IP of both VMs with bridge network was 192.168.100.12 and 192.168.100.17. 
The `hostname -I` for master:

```
192.168.100.17 172.17.0.1 10.32.0.1 10.32.0.2
```

The `hostname -I` for worker-node:

```
192.168.100.12 172.17.0.1 10.44.0.0 10.32.0.1
```

`journalctl -xeu kubelet` shows the following:

https://gist.github.com/saad749/9a771a3460bf88c274498b5bc4b7fd84

While trying with flannel (and still the same issue), the result from

```
kubectl describe nodes
```

is

https://gist.github.com/saad749/d24c453c8b4e663e9abf572a0fb38bf4

**Am I missing any step before kubeadm init? Should I change the IP addresses (to what)? Are there any specific logs I should look into? Is there a more comprehensive tutorial for this?
All Issues start after kubeadm join on the worker node, I can deploy the kubernetes on the master node or any other stuff, and it works fine.**

**UPDATE:**

Even after applying the suggestions from errordeveloper, The same issue persists.

I add the following flag to kubeadm init:

```
--apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.100.17
```

I updated the kubeadm.conf to following and did reload and restart:
https://gist.github.com/saad749/c7149c87ec3e75a40586f626cf04279a

and  also tried changing the cluster dns
https://gist.github.com/saad749/5fa66bebc22841e58119333e75600e40

This the log from after initializing the master:

```
kube-master@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP               NODE
kube-system   etcd-ubuntu                      1/1       Running   0          22s       192.168.100.17   ubuntu
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ubuntu            1/1       Running   0          29s       192.168.100.17   ubuntu
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ubuntu   1/1       Running   0          13s       192.168.100.17   ubuntu
kube-system   kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-wfqhb         3/3       Running   0          1m        10.32.0.7        ubuntu
kube-system   kube-proxy-h4hz9                 1/1       Running   0          1m        192.168.100.17   ubuntu
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ubuntu            1/1       Running   0          34s       192.168.100.17   ubuntu
kube-system   weave-net-fkgnh                  2/2       Running   0          32s       192.168.100.17   ubuntu
```

The hostname -i results:

```
kube-master@ubuntu:~$ hostname -I
192.168.100.17 172.17.0.1 10.32.0.1 10.32.0.2 10.32.0.3 10.32.0.4 10.32.0.5 10.32.0.6 10.244.0.0 10.244.0.1
kube-master@ubuntu:~$ hostname -i
192.168.100.17
```

Results from:

```
kubectl describe nodes
```

https://gist.github.com/saad749/8f460650182a04d0ddf3158a52761a9a

The Internal IP seems correct now.

After joining from second node, this happens:

```
kube-master@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ubuntu    Ready     master    49m       v1.9.3
kube-master@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE       IP               NODE
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ubuntu   0/1       Pending             0          0s        <none>           ubuntu
kube-system   kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-wfqhb         0/3       ContainerCreating   0          49m       <none>           ubuntu
kube-system   kube-proxy-h4hz9                 1/1       Running             0          49m       192.168.100.17   ubuntu
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ubuntu            1/1       Running             0          1s        192.168.100.17   ubuntu
kube-system   weave-net-fkgnh                  2/2       Running             0          48m       192.168.100.17   ubuntu
```

ifconfig -a results:

https://gist.github.com/saad749/63a5a52bd3246ff72477b2aca7d158d0

journalctl -xeu kubelet results

https://gist.github.com/saad749/8a60870b35f93df8565e66cb208aff32

Sometimes, the pods IP is shown at 192.168.100.12 which is the IP of the non-master second node.

```
kube-master@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP               NODE
kube-system   etcd-ubuntu                      0/1       Pending   0          0s        <none>           ubuntu
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ubuntu            0/1       Pending   0          0s        <none>           ubuntu
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ubuntu   1/1       Running   0          0s        192.168.100.12   ubuntu
kube-system   kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-wfqhb         2/3       Running   0          3h        10.32.0.7        ubuntu
kube-system   kube-proxy-h4hz9                 1/1       Running   0          3h        192.168.100.12   ubuntu
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ubuntu            0/1       Pending   0          0s        <none>           ubuntu
kube-system   weave-net-fkgnh                  2/2       Running   1          3h        192.168.100.17   ubuntu

kube-master@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP               NODE
kube-system   kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-wfqhb   3/3       Running   0          3h        10.32.0.7        ubuntu
kube-system   kube-proxy-h4hz9           1/1       Running   0          3h        192.168.100.12   ubuntu
kube-system   weave-net-fkgnh            2/2       Running   0          3h        192.168.100.12   ubuntu


kubectl describe nodes
Name:               ubuntu
Roles:              master
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ubuntu
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 02 Mar 2018 08:21:47 -0800
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  OutOfDisk        False   Fri, 02 Mar 2018 11:38:36 -0800   Fri, 02 Mar 2018 08:21:43 -0800   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure   False   Fri, 02 Mar 2018 11:38:36 -0800   Fri, 02 Mar 2018 08:21:43 -0800   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Fri, 02 Mar 2018 11:38:36 -0800   Fri, 02 Mar 2018 08:21:43 -0800   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  Ready            True    Fri, 02 Mar 2018 11:38:36 -0800   Fri, 02 Mar 2018 11:28:25 -0800   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.100.12
  Hostname:    ubuntu
Capacity:
 cpu:     4
 memory:  6080832Ki
 pods:    110
Allocatable:
 cpu:     4
 memory:  5978432Ki
 pods:    110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 59bf65b835b242a3aa182f4b8a542219
 System UUID:                0C3C4D56-4747-D59E-EE09-F16F2793677E
 Boot ID:                    658b4a08-d724-425e-9246-2b41995ecc46
 Kernel Version:             4.13.0-36-generic
 OS Image:                   Ubuntu 17.10
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://1.13.1
 Kubelet Version:            v1.9.3
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.9.3
ExternalID:                  ubuntu
Non-terminated Pods:         (3 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  kube-system                kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-wfqhb    260m (6%)     0 (0%)      110Mi (1%)       170Mi (2%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-h4hz9            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                weave-net-fkgnh             20m (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  280m (7%)     0 (0%)      110Mi (1%)       170Mi (2%)
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                 From             Message
  ----     ------                   ----                ----             -------
  Warning  Rebooted                 12m (x814 over 2h)  kubelet, ubuntu  Node ubuntu has been rebooted, boot id: 16efd500-a2a5-446f-ba25-1187857996e0
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    10m                 kubelet, ubuntu  Node ubuntu status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   Starting                 10m                 kubelet, ubuntu  Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  10m                 kubelet, ubuntu  Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientDisk    10m                 kubelet, ubuntu  Node ubuntu status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  10m                 kubelet, ubuntu  Node ubuntu status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeNotReady             10m                 kubelet, ubuntu  Node ubuntu status is now: NodeNotReady
  Warning  Rebooted                 2m (x870 over 2h)   kubelet, ubuntu  Node ubuntu has been rebooted, boot id: 658b4a08-d724-425e-9246-2b41995ecc46
  Warning  Rebooted                 15s (x60 over 10m)  kubelet, ubuntu  Node ubuntu has been rebooted, boot id: 16efd500-a2a5-446f-ba25-1187857996e0
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: When the `weave-net` pod is running, get the logs from the `weave` container via `kubectl logs -n kube-system weave-net-xxxx`.  It hasn't initialized CNI, which suggests it detected an error.

Comment: Yes, logs would certainly help to identify the issue more closely, but see my answer below also.

Comment: @Bryan : The command doesnt runs. says: 
kubectl logs -n kube-system weave-net-fkgnh

    Error from server (BadRequest): a container name must be specified for pod weave-net-fkgnh, choose one of: [weave weave-npc]

Comment: For the record, you add the `weave` container name at the end, so it would be `kubectl logs -n kube-system weave-net-fkgnh weave`

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after following the advice from @errordeveloper and still hitting the wall, I was able to solve the issue that turns out to be pretty simple.

Both my VMs had the same hostname.

```
hostname -f
```

would return

```
ubuntu
```

on both, and that causes issue with kubernetes, apparently.

I changed the name on my non-master node with

```
hostnamectl set-hostname kminion
```

and in the following files:

```
/etc/hostname
/etc/hosts
```

and everything went smooth onward!

Comment: `/etc/hostname` should be set by `hostnamectl set-hostname`.

Comment: Did you have to restart anything? I'm getting the same behavior after running those commands.

Comment: No, I dont remember, restarting the system. but if you have already init the cluster, it might help resetting it and init again.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I change the IP addresses (to what)?

Yes, this is typically the way to make things work on VMs where the default route is for NATed access to the Internet.

You want to use the IP of the bridge network, for you master that appears to be `192.168.100.17` (but please double check).

First, please try using `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.100.17`, but that may not solve all of the issues.

In your ouput of `kubectl describe nodes`, I can see this

```
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  172.17.0.1
  Hostname:    ubuntu
```

So you probably want to make sure that kubelet also doesn't used the NATed interface, for which you would need to use kubelet's `--node-ip` flag.

However, there are other ways to fix this problem, e.g. if you can ensure that `hostname -i` returns the IP of the bridged interface (which you can do by tweaking `/etc/hosts`).

Comment: Thank you. How and where can I set the kubelet's --node-ip flag?

Comment: You will need to use a systemd drop-in unit to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit noob with this, can you direct to any resource with more directions? How to use a systemd drop-in unit?

Comment: For general info about systemd drop-ins, take a look [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) and 
 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services) is one of the general use-cases for it.

For kubeadm-specific info, take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#kubelet-drop-in).

Comment: Essentially, you can edit `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`, or add `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/05-node-ip.conf` where you can define `Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip=<ipaddr>"`, but don't forget to run `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart kubelet` for these changes to take effect.

Comment: That approach is easy to try in order to determine if the issue is with the IP address... however, I'd recommend tweaking `/etc/hosts` to point `hostname -i` at the IP of the bridged interface.

Comment: I tried all the suggested steps, but the result is still the same. I have updated the question, with the logs after applying the steps. What am I missing?